# Cloudwatch dashboard: widgets with independent time ranges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

#### I would like each widget in my Dashboard to have its own time range

I can't find a way to do this, and I would find it mind boggling if it's not possible.
I would like my Dashboard to contain the following *stacked areas* widgets:

- RequestCount from the past hour with 30 seconds periods (i.e. 120 plot points)
- RequestCount from the past day with 1 hour periods (i.e. 24 plot points)
- RequestCount from the past week with 6 hour periods (i.e. 28 plot points)

However, I can't seem to enforce each widget's time range (only their periods), and the Dashboard's time range overrides everything, regardless of what I had previously set in each widget.

**Is there a way for each widget to maintain its original time range?**

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this ?

Comment: Nope. I felt super limited with cloudwatch so I ended up abandoning it and fully switching to ELK stack. It’s been great so far, but way way more to setup